# How to Change Apache Superset Template from the Superset User Interface?

Tags: apache-superset

The Apache Superset UI has a CSS template tab, which can be used apparently to edit and change the UI skin. 
I tried editing the the CSS sheet but nothing is changing, Am I missing something?
What will be the best way to change Apache Superset skin.

Comment: What version of Superset are you using? Can you update with the CSS you tried to apply? Did you apply it to a specific dashboard and get no results?

Answer (score 13):

The Superset documentation is a bit sparse and I was unable to find clear instructions on how to do this. I'm leaving an answer that will hopefully save others time.

Note: tested on Apache Superset v0.22.1

**Creating a CSS template**

- Login to Superset with an account that has admin privileges
- [Go to **Manage**. Then **CSS Templates**.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivrD3.jpg) This will take you to a page showing all the available templates.
- Create a new CSS template by clicking the [**+** icon in the top right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCgbH.jpg).
- [Specify the **Template Name** and **Css**. Click **Save**.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xW2U6.jpg)

**Applying a CSS template**

How it works in Superset is you manually apply the templates to dashboards. So with that in mind ...

- Go to the dashboard whose CSS you'd like to change
- [Click **Edit Dashboard**.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p53fV.jpg) It should be available in the top right. If you can't see the Edit Dashboard button then that means you don't have the required privileges to make any changes to the dashboard.
- [Click the **Actions** dropdown button and go all the way down to **Edit CSS**.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pt3qO.jpg) This will allow you to access all the templates that you'd created previously in step 1. Select the template you want. During the selection process, the CSS will be applied automatically and you can get a *preview* of how it's going to look.
- Once you have selected a template. Go back to the [**Actions** dropdown button but this time click **Save**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pt3qO.jpg) to save your changes.

That's all there is to it!