# how to change apache superset's chart's background color?

Tags: apache-superset

Per [How to Change Apache Superset Template from the Superset User Interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50043278/how-to-change-apache-superset-template-from-the-superset-user-interface) , I was able to change the CSS template for Superset dashboard. But the charts inside the dashboard are not affected. e.g. most of the charts have white colored background(e.g. Piechart) and some people dislike it. How to change the chart background color? I mean change it for all charts or for one chart.
[image: The background I'd like to change in Apache Superset]

Answer (score 5):

Disclaimer: This should work, but is a bit hacky and could have long-term support implications:

I've been fiddling with a "dark mode" dashboard just to kick the tires on this. Here's a screenshot just for fun:

[image: Superset dark mode example]

So... what did I do?

1. Click "Edit Dashboard" in the top right of your screenshot
2. When in edit mode, the top right menu has an option to "Edit CSS"
3. Use your browser's inspector to hack away! That said, here are a couple of key ingredients:

   - `.dashboard-component{ background: whatever}` - sets the main background of each viz card, but you'll still see many components still have white backgrounds within these wrappers.
   - `.slice_container  svg{
     background-color: transparent !important;
     }` - this overrides the white background of the components I ran into (including Pie charts!).

If viz components use SVG you can get pretty clever with inspecting/overriding various bits. A couple of gotchas with the above:

1. If a viz component contains multiple SVG elements, this may have side effects.
2. If a viz uses `canvas` instead of `svg` you will run into more trouble

In the worst case scenario, you may need to check out the `superset-ui-plugins` repo and make tweaks. This dev process isn't super straightforward, but some of us are working to improve that.

Comment: How did you set the text content as white?

Comment: SVG has its own schema of elements... you'll want to target the `text` element (which might have a handy class as well) with an attribute of `fill: #666` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution for me is using [dark reader](https://darkreader.org/) extension.